# How to save date in Laravel in GMT 0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How to save date in GTM 0 in database?

I mean this: `protected $dates = ['created_at'];`

Comment: I think you mean timezones which would be set in the config of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally recommend leaving/setting the timezone in your app config as UTC rather than GMT:
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

To make sure my custom date fields are stored correctly I use a modifier on my model class like so:

```
public function setStartAtAttribute($date)
{
    $timezone = (Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->profile->timezone : config('pgn.phoenix.timezone'));
    $tzdate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $date, $timezone);

    $this->attributes['start_at'] = $tzdate->timezone('UTC');
}
```

That would need `use Carbon\Carbon;` adding to the top of your model too.

That config param above is set to 'Europe/London' and is the timezone that our guests are shown dates, (works with daylight savings) whilst not affecting the 'system' timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the timezone of the application by going to the config/app.php file and changinf the following line:

`'timezone' => 'GMT'`

If your dates are still saved in a different timezone, it is likely that the server datetime will need to be altered to GMT. This can be done using the following command and following the instructions:

`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`